# Symfony2: Persist roles as an array or object?

Tags: security, symfony, doctrine, roles

Is there a reason for roles to get persisted as an extra object or should I just save them as an array in the `$roles` property of my `User` entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends. If you don't need to do special queries based on roles and/or don't mind locking yourself to a particular database vendor supporting arrays, persisting as an array will do.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!
Another point what would be interesting is if the creation of roles is a common task?

Comment: Unless you want to hack the security system, you'll define roles in the `security.yml` config file and will just persist the users' roles in an array or something else.

Comment: Ok, than I think I will progress this way. Thank you for the info :)